# private var does not work as expected in a class php

Tags: php, class, private, var

In the example below I receive an error stating the value of `$foo->_test` is not accessible since it is private.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$foo = new Bar;
$foo->test();
print_r( $foo->_test );

class Foo
{
    private $_test = array();
}


class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function test()
    {
        $this->_test = 'opa';
    }
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If I answered your question please accept it. If not, please ask some questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Private variables are only visible to the direct class in which they are declared.  What you're looking for is `protected`  Without this you are effectively creating two different member variables in your object.

```
class Foo
{
    protected $_test = array();
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function test()
    {
        $this->_test = 'opa';
    }
}
```

[edit]
You're also attempting to access a private (soon to be protected) member variable outside the class completely.  This will **always** be disallowed. Except in this case, you're creating a second, `public` member variable which is why there is no error displayed.  You didn't mention that you expected to see an error, so I'm assuming this is a question you had.

[edit]

**here is the var dump:**

```
object(Bar)#1 (2) {
  ["_test:private"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_test"]=>
  string(3) "opa"
}
```

[edit]

One thing I've done in a framework I wrote is to create a base class that I extend almost everywhere.  One thing this class does is use the `__get` and `__set` methods to enforce declaring class member variables - it helps narrow down code problems such as the one you had.

```
<?

abstract class tgsfBase
{
    public function __get( $name )
    {
        throw new Exception( 'Undefined class member "' . $name . "\"\nYou must declare all variables you'll be using in the class definition." );
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public function __set( $name, $value )
    {
        throw new Exception( 'SET: Undeclared class variable ' . $name . "\nYou must declare all variables you'll be using in the class definition." );
    }

}

class Foo extends tgsfBase
{
    private $_test = array();
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function test()
    {
        $this->_test = 'opa';
    }
}

header( 'content-type:text/plain');

$foo = new Bar;
$foo->test();
var_dump( $foo );
print_r( $foo->_test );
```

Comment: this will show an error `Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SET: Undeclared class variable _test`

Answer (score 0):

Private member is not `visible` in its sub-classes. For more info read the [Manaul](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). Add var_dump() to verify the object structure.

```
<?php
  $foo = new Bar;
  $foo->teste();
  print_r( $foo->_testando );
  var_dump( $foo);

  class Foo
  {
    private $_testando = array();
   }
 class Bar extends Foo
  {
  public function teste()
   {
   $this->_testando  = 'opa';  // a new member of string type will be created 
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: If you copy this code, save to a php file and run, see the output of the variable as if it were public. I wanted to know why this error happens.

Comment: @user1068478 - If member is visible then you have to correct the statment - correction should be : `$this->_testando[]  = 'opa';`

Answer (score 0):

When you will write the `var_dump($foo);` below the `$foo->teste();` you will get the complete idea.

Here PHP have created 2 varaibles with name **_testando**, one is private having value = array() and one is public having value = opa.

Write this:

```
private $_testando_new = '';
```

above the public function teste()

and replace `$this->_testando = 'opa';` with `$this->_testando_new = 'opa';`

and try to access **_testando_new** variable outside the class, you will get the error.

Bye.